# Фильтр буфера обмена на сайте JS

Tags: javascript

Использую на своем сайт копирование информации из одного окна в другое. 
Проблема такая что при копировании например span в другое место он вставляет полностью весь тэг html, а хотелось бы только текст чистый, можно его как то отформатировать на js?

Comment: Можно сначала в текстовый редактор вставить с отменой форматирования, а потом уже на сайт. Или на сайте использовать нормальный wysiwyg редактор, который умеет при вставке убирать форматирование. Например этот умеет https://www.tinymce.com

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

```
-webkit-user-select: text;
-moz-user-select: text;
-ms-user-select: text;
user-select: text;
```

А Опера 12- и так только текст копирует.

---

> @Qweriy, это работает только для выделения, для копирования не помогает

Оказывается, действительно так. Не ожидал.

```css
div {
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Some spans of <span style=color:red>red</span> and <span style=color:green>green</span> colors.
</div>

<div contenteditable>
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: @Qweriy, это работает только для выделения, для копирования не помогает